# After failover Pacemaker moves resource back when node comes back

Tags: linux, cluster, pacemaker, corosync

I'm using Pacemaker & Corosync for my cluster.
When a node dies pacemaker moving my resources to another online node. Everything ok here.
But when the dead node comes back, Pacemaker moving the resource back.
I don't have any "location" line in my config and also I tried with "unmove" command but nothing changed.

I failed at somewhere and need to find the reason.

**crm configure sh**

```
node 1: DEV1
node 2: DEV2
primitive poolip IPaddr2 \
    params ip=10.1.60.33 nic=enp2s0f0 cidr_netmask=24 \
    meta migration-threshold=2 target-role=Started \
    op monitor interval=20 timeout=20 on-fail=restart
primitive gui systemd:gui \
    op monitor interval=20s \
    meta target-role=Started
primitive gui-ip IPaddr2 \
    params ip=10.1.60.35 nic=enp2s0f0 cidr_netmask=24 \
    meta migration-threshold=2 target-role=Started \
    op monitor interval=20 timeout=20 on-fail=restart
colocation cluster-gui inf: gui gui-ip
order gui-after-ip Mandatory: gui-ip gui
property cib-bootstrap-options: \
    have-watchdog=false \
    dc-version=2.0.0-1-8cf3fe749e \
    cluster-infrastructure=corosync \
    cluster-name=mycluster \
    stonith-enabled=false \
    no-quorum-policy=ignore \
    last-lrm-refresh=1545920437
rsc_defaults rsc-options: \
    migration-threshold=10 \
    resource-stickiness=100
```

**pcs resource defaults**

```
migration-threshold=10
resource-stickiness=100
```

**pcs resource show gui**

```
Resource: gui (class=systemd type=gui)
 Meta Attrs: target-role=Started
 Operations: monitor interval=20s (gui-monitor-20s)
```

Comment: does `pcs constraint show` show anything?

Comment: I don't use pcs but i have installed for you.   
pcs constraint show
```
Location Constraints:
Ordering Constraints:
  gui-ip then gui (kind:Mandatory)
Colocation Constraints:
  gui with gui-ip (score:INFINITY)
Ticket Constraints:
```

Comment: It would help if you could click the "Edit" link below your question and edit the additional information into the question instead. It's hard to read the info when it's in a comment.

Comment: I think you should have a look at stickiness. Since you've got pcs installed now, check it by running `pcs resource defaults`and `pcs resource show gui`

Comment: @JennyD outputs are added.

Comment: Are you starting services at boot that Pacemaker is monitoring? If so, it's possible that Pacemaker notices the service is running in both places, and is stopping services on the current primary and leaving them running on the freshly rebooted node.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be starting services at boot that only the cluster should be start/stop/monitoring.

Disable your services from starting at boot and then test your reboot again: `systemctl disable gui`

Comment: No, I dont start my services via systemd.